# What is $\lim v_n$ if $v_1=1$ and $v_{n+1}=\sqrt{v_n^2+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^n}$ for $n\ge 1$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{v_n\}$ be a sequence defined by $v_1=1$ and $v_{n+1}=\sqrt{v_{n}^2 + \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^n}$ for $n\ge 1$. Then  find  $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} v_n$.

I take  $v_n = v_{n+1} =  l$,   now i  have $l^2 = l^2 + 0$ that  is $l = 1$  so $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} v_n= 1$

Is its correct ? Any hints/solution

Comment: No, $l^2= l^2+ 0$ does NOT give "l= 1".  It is true for all l.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not correct. Note that $l^2=l^2$ is true for any number.

Set $x_n:=v_n^2$. From your recursion you get $x_{n+1}=x_n+(\frac{1}{5})^n$ and $x_1=1$, and hence the explicit formula
$$
x_n=x_1+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^j=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^j.
$$
This geometric series converges to $\frac{5}{4}$, and therefore, $(v_n)$ converges to 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}.
$$